# Проблемы с Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Я создаю приложение на xamarin.forms. Утром открываю проект, пишу код, вечером закрываю проект, выключаю компьютер. Но после этого visual studio ломается. Когда я пытаюсь запустить проект(на эмуляторе, либо на телефоне) происходит это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядят свойтсва MyProject.Android:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже если, я вручную введу имя сборки и т.д., сохраню файл, закрою и открою его заново, я все равно увижу пустые поля. Причем, если открыть файл MyProject.Android.csproj через блокнот, то ничего такого, что могло бы послужить причиной ошибки, там не будет. Такая же ситуация и с файлом .sln. Таким образом я уже создал 2-3 новых проекта(при создании нового проекта всё работает). Я использую самую свежую версию vs, отключено большинство расширений.

Раньше такого не было, и я не знаю причины, из-за которой это началось. Также интересно то, что после того, как я безуспешено пытался запустить проект, я обновил vs, и после  этого я смог его запустить. Но на следующий день все повторилось. Сборки/пересборки и перестройки не помогают. Также я пытался скопировать вечером проект на флешку и запустить его утром -  не получилось.

Comment: наверно текст ошибок не помешал бы... и попробуйте еще папку .vs удалить

Comment: @Vasek текста ошибки нет.......

Comment: а в [output](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: @Vasek в выводе написано, что проект просто "Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1..." и

Comment: в этих окнах ничего интересного я не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то нужно, то я в итоге не смог починить vs. Мне пришлось полностью переустанавливать студию, чего мне очень не хотелось, после этого данная проблема исчезла.